# How to Download Windows Azure Cloud Service Definition .csdef File

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

Does anyone know how to download Azure Cloud Service definition .csdef file using C# or PowerShell  commands?

Comment: Is there any way to download it programmatically?

Comment: by something like bashing you mean?

Comment: Preferably using C#. If there is no API then bashing can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't download `csdef` file directly (though you can download `config file (cscfg)`) because the `csdef` file gets bundled in the package file (`cspkg`).

Comment: Is there anyway to edit it like adding some subsites under site tag etc. without downloading the csdef?

Comment: You can download the CSPKG and unpackage it (it is just a ZIP file).  Doing this you can see the CSDEF, but you still can't dynamically modify it.  If you want to change it you need to redeploy a new CSPKG.